# ERROR c2955 : using c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename Elem>
class linkeddeque {
private:
dlinkedlist<Elem> d;
int n;
public:
    ...
    void sum_average();
};

template<typename Elem> void linkeddeque::sum_average() {   //C2955
    cout << "Error!" << endl;
}

template <> void linkeddeque<double>::sum_average() {
    int ss = n;
    double sum = 0;
    double temp[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
        temp[i] = back();
        sum = sum + back();
        removeback();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ss; i++) {
        insertfront(temp[i]);
    }
    double aver = sum / ss;
    cout << "sum : " << sum << " average : " << aver << endl;
}
```

I want to use specialization to customize sum_average for int/double/float.
So, I used specialization to function but occured error.
Hope anyone can tell what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Please post the complete error message verbatim in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code of defining the member function of class template is wrong. Change

```
template<typename Elem> void linkeddeque::sum_average() {
```

to

```
template<typename Elem> void linkeddeque<Elem>::sum_average() {
                                        ~~~~~~
```

Anyway, the error seems to have nothing to do with the specialization.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/YAG86543)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't template your `sum_average()` method correctly:

```
template<typename Elem> void linkeddeque<Elem>::sum_average() {
//                                  ~~~~^^^^^^~~~
    cout << "Error!" << endl;
}
```